# C# SQL Server database connection without native application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am looking for a suggestion, how can I connect database without writing the connection string in the native application.

I am using this but looking for another so that, when I rename database, the software will connect automatically.

```
static string conStr = @"server=myServerName;Integrated Security=true;Connection Timeout=5;Database=myDatabaseName;";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the connection string in the configuration file.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="server=myServerName;Integrated Security=true;Connection Timeout=5;Database=myDatabaseName;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then to retrieve the string you want you use:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString
```

Asking for it to connect automatically even if you rename the database isn't possible. Think about it, a single server can host hundreds of databases. How would it know which one to connect to?

Comment: A project reference to the System.Configuration assembly is needed to use this method.